# How to get metrics for use of Facebook social plugins?

Tags: analytics, facebook

I have a site with hundreds of content pages. Each content page has a Facebook like button on it. Aside from browsing to each page and reading the number next to each Like button, how can I get information about the number of likes across my whole website? There doesn't seem to be any tools on Facebook that allow me to do this.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking this is exactly what [Facebook Insights](http://mashable.com/2010/06/07/facebook-insights-dashboard/) is designed for.

I haven't tried any of these yet, but there are also a few social media analytics services out there that might help you track this data.

Comment: Thank you. As odd as it sounds, I didn't know about that site. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @jessegavin: I didn't either until you asked this question ;-P